# Wordpress php script to control widget

Tags: php, wordpress

There are several default widgets in WordPress, which php script file is controlling the widget's coding and its CSS declaration?

I simple add an image into a text widget and put it in different sidebar, there are different result come out.

I put the tag `<img src="ad_here.jpg">` in bottom sidebar and it generate below div block and it works properly.

```
<div class="span4">
    <div id="text-5" class="widget widget_text">
        <div class="textwidget"><img src="ad_here.jpg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I put the tag in another sidebar which is located in header section, it generates below div block and don't know why there is additional text after the block, the "1    ". When image is viewed in full width, the image covers the  "1    ", when I narrow the browser width, the image is resized responsively and at last the image is not big enough to cover the  text "1    ".

Problem can be seen here:

[image]

```
<div class="span5">
    <div class="banner-ads">
        <div class="textwidget"><img src="ad_here.jpg"></div>
    </div>1
</div>
```

Do anyone have some advise to me how I can troubleshoot the problem, which php script file may cause this problem?

Comment: Which wordpress theme you are using?

Comment: I am using the Realia theme, it is 3rd party theme I brought from http://themeforest.net/item/realia-responsive-real-estate-wordpress-theme/4789838. I don't think it is not affected by the theme because same code apply different sidebar and get different result.